# Access 2013: Reference with variables to an object with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, object, ms-access, reference

I'm trying to make a loop with VBA and check for different Access fields (named "Areas") if they are True or False.

If three Areas are True, my Sub should return their names (i.e. "AreaA, AreaF, AreaG").

The problem is, I'm getting an error: "**Compile error. Type Mismatch.**" in the line shown below and the second "**&**" is highlighted.

```
Set chkObject = "[Forms]![1110 Datos]![Area_" & Area(i) & "]"
```

These are some existent objects (checkboxes):

**[Forms]![1110 Datos]![Area_Cnc]**

**[Forms]![1110 Datos]![Area_Emb]**

**[Forms]![1110 Datos]![Area_Ens]**

Here's my code:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim Area() As String, Vars As String, i As Integer, chkObject As Object
Dim strAreas As String
Vars = "Cnc, Emb, Ens, Esp, Fer, For, Maq, Pin, Pon, Sie, Sol, Tel, Rou"

Area = Split(Vars, ", ")
strAreas = "" 'Set blank.

For i = 0 To UBound(Area)
    Set chkObject = "[Forms]![1110 Datos]![Area_" & Area(i) & "]" 'Reference to the Object.

    If chkObject.Value = True Then
        If strAreas = "" Then 'Check if it is the first Area: "Cnc" OR "Esp"...
            strAreas = Area(i)
        Else
            strAreas = strAreas & ", " & Area(i) 'To add commas if already exists one checked: "Cnc, Esp, Sie"
        End If
    End If

If strAreas = "" Then 'If no Areas were checked...
    Debug.Print "Ningún area estaba activa."
Else
    Debug.Print strAreas 'Else, return selected Areas
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to reference this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you don't need "Set" keyword as chkObject seams to be a string

Comment: `Forms("1110 Datos").Controls("Area_" & Area(i)).Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code, thank you Tim:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim Area() As String, Vars As String, i As Integer, chkObject As Object
Dim strAreas As String
Vars = "Cnc, Emb, Ens, Esp, Fer, For, Maq, Pin, Pon, Sie, Sol, Tel, Rou"

Area = Split(Vars, ", ")
strAreas = ""

For i = 0 To UBound(Area)
    Set chkObject = Forms("1110 Datos").Controls("Area_" & Area(i))

    If chkObject.Value = True Then
        If strAreas = "" Then
            strAreas = Area(i)
        Else
            strAreas = strAreas & ", " & Area(i)
        End If
    End If
Next

If strAreas = "" Then
    Debug.Print "Ningún area estaba activa."
Else
    Debug.Print strAreas
End If

End Sub
```